# Datatable in ajax jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I would like to combine datatables with dynamically loaded jquery tabs and don't know how to do it.

Here is my code:

*index.jsp*:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
                    ui.panel.html(
                      "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. "+ 
                      "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
                });
            }
        });

        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
```

---

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="ajax/tab.jsp?a=1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/tab.jsp?a=2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/tab.jsp?a=3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/tab.jsp?a=4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*tab.jsp*:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

When we click Tab it will load `ajax/tab.jsp?a=1` in a dynamic div.

So this happens each time you click a Tab.

But your `Datatable` code is written just once which will get executed before the `jsp` file is loaded

So your datatable doest show up.

To resolve this

1. You need to call `$('#example').DataTable();` each time a Tab is clicked
2. And make sure you call if after your jsp content is loaded.

You can use [tabsbeforeload](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeLoad) event of Tabs.

**Note:**

I have added timeout just to delay things so that jsp is loaded.
If yous jsp takes more time to load try increasing timeout value.

**Code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#tabs").tabs({
                    beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
                    // load first time
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#example').DataTable();
                        }, 30);

                        ui.jqXHR.fail(function () {
                            ui.panel.html(
                                "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                                "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                        });
                    }
                });

                // before tabload
                $("#tabs").on("tabsbeforeload", function (event, ui) {
                    console.log("dd");
                    $("#example").remove();  // to avoide duplicate id as Datatable will not load for other Tabs
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#example').DataTable();
                    }, 30);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="ajax/tab.jsp?a=1">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="ajax/tab.jsp?a=2">Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="ajax/tab.jsp?a=3">Tab 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="ajax/tab.jsp?a=4">Tab 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I wil try it and let you know if it works for me :)